# Transform attributes in request body

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I have used `@Transform` decorator from `class-transformer` to sanitize specific fields in user input.

```js
import { IsString } from "class-validator";
import { Transform } from "class-transformer";

export class SearchRequestDto {
  @Transform((data) => data.value && sanitizeRegex(data.value))
  @IsString()
  readonly term: string = '';
}
```

How can I create a new decorator to add this transformer to DTO more straight forward. Like this:

```js
export class SearchRequestDto {
  @Regex()
  @IsString()
  readonly term: string = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Decorator that looks like this:

```
export const Regex = () => Transform((data) => data.value && sanitizeRegex(data.value))
```

And then use it the way you wanted:

```
export class SearchRequestDto {
  @Regex()
  @IsString()
  readonly term: string = '';
}
```